# What is nameser_compat.h and why isnt it being included?

Tags: c, macos, bind

I am trying to get some code to compile that is trying to use some definitions in the nameser_compat.h header file. This file is apparently included as part of nameser.h if some BIND compatibility is set.

I am ttrying to compile on OSX and apparently this value is not set because it is not pulling the file in. Should I manually import nameser_compat.h into my code in additon to nameser.h?

Comment: to see if it is really included, you need to call gcc with -E, which stops the compilation after the preprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac OS X 10.7.4 machine, I can find three relevant looking files:

```
/usr/include/arpa/nameser.h
/usr/include/arpa/nameser_compat.h
/usr/include/nameser.h
```

I took this trivial piece of code (in a file `xx.c`):

```
#include <nameser.h>
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

and compiled it like this to get the output shown:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -DBIND_8_COMPAT -H -c xx.c
. /usr/include/nameser.h
.. /usr/include/arpa/nameser_compat.h
... /usr/include/machine/endian.h
.... /usr/include/i386/endian.h
..... /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
...... /usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
...... /usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
..... /usr/include/sys/_endian.h
...... /usr/include/libkern/_OSByteOrder.h
....... /usr/include/sys/_types.h
........ /usr/include/machine/_types.h
......... /usr/include/i386/_types.h
....... /usr/include/libkern/i386/_OSByteOrder.h
.. /usr/include/sys/param.h
... /usr/include/sys/types.h
.... /usr/include/sys/appleapiopts.h
.... /usr/include/machine/types.h
..... /usr/include/i386/types.h
...... /usr/include/i386/_types.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_structs.h
... /usr/include/sys/syslimits.h
... /usr/include/machine/param.h
.... /usr/include/i386/param.h
..... /usr/include/i386/_param.h
... /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h
.... /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/syslimits.h
.... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h
..... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/syslimits.h
..... /usr/include/limits.h
...... /usr/include/machine/limits.h
....... /usr/include/i386/limits.h
........ /usr/include/i386/_limits.h
... /usr/include/sys/signal.h
.... /usr/include/machine/signal.h
..... /usr/include/i386/signal.h
...... /usr/include/i386/_structs.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_structs.h
..... /usr/include/machine/_structs.h
...... /usr/include/i386/_structs.h
....... /usr/include/mach/i386/_structs.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
$
```

That shows that with `-DBIND_8_COMPAT` set, the `nameser_compat.h` header is included.  The source code shows that would be expected:

```
#ifndef _NAMESER_9_H_
#define _NAMESER_9_H_

#ifdef BIND_8_COMPAT
#include <arpa/nameser_compat.h>
#endif
```